# What is the .Trash Folder on the NTFS partitions?

Tags: dual-boot, ntfs, trash

When using a dual-boot Windows and Ubuntu. I see that there is a folder created with the name `.Trash-1000`  in the NTFS partitions.

Could someone explain to me :

- What does this folder mean ?
- For what it is used? Maybe Trash related?
- Is it necessary to keep this folder ?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

For every mountpoint Ubuntu creates `.Trash` directory when a file is deleted.

The `1000` is the UID of the user that created the bin, so every user can have their own.

> Is it necessary to keep this folder ?

I think it is your choice. It just a bin folder, If you need a bin folder for your mount HD you can keep it.

If you want Ubuntu prevent creating this directory:

- Don't use the delete button only (Otherwise the `.Trash-1000` folder will be created)
- Press the key combination <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Delete</kbd> together to delete, then Ubuntu won't create a `.Trash-1000` folder.

**Note for 12.04:** Under 12.04 i noticed that `.trash` directory recreated even if you deleted with <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Delete</kbd>

**Note**:  If you delete this directory files and folders this way they are gone forever

Answer (score 1):

It is like a Trash bin for the files you deleted.
The 1000 is the user UID, so every user can get a different Trash bin folder.

This usually happens when youu delete a file from a NTFS partition and not shift and delete them.
So if the folder is empty or you don't need those deleted files it's ok to delete it.